# Move filtered elements before hidden ones

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a very special filter to elements shaped like hexagons which have strict top and left attributes.
When filtering elements I would like these hexagons moving to top instead of leaving space in the hidden ones.

https://codepen.io/skebby/pen/EqNwga

```
<div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary filter-button" data-filter="all">Tutti</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="prodotti">Prodotti</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="servizi">Servizi</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="infestanti">Infestanti</button>
    </div>

  <div id="grid" class="filter-sections" style="position: relative; margin-bottom: 20px;">
      
<div class="filter prodotti infestanti"><a href="bees" target="_blank"><img class="hex col1 row1 mb-1" src="http://hexb.in/hexagons/757rb.png" alt="for bees"></a></div>
      
<div class="filter servizi infestanti "> <a href="/spiders" target="_blank"><img class="hex col2 row1 mb-2" src="http://hexb.in/hexagons/adventure-js.png" alt="Products for spiders"></a></div>
      
<div class="filter infestanti prodotti servizi "><a href="/wasps" target="_blank"><img class="hex col3 row1 mb-3" src="http://hexb.in/hexagons/airgidfaolchu.png" alt="Products for spiders" ></a></div>

<div class="filter prodotti"><a href="/snakes" target="_blank"><img class="hex col4 row1 mb-4" src="http://hexb.in/hexagons/broom.png" alt="/" ></a></div>
      
      
<div class="filter servizi prodotti"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img class="hex col5 row1 mb-5" src="http://hexb.in/hexagons/antifaschistische-aktion.png"></a></div>
      
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a live example?

Comment: @ultrarun Updated with codepen

Comment: You are using absolute positioning so even though some dissappear the others will still hold their postion. Floating with CSS may be an option but would still need maybe relative positioning due to the irregular shapes, tricky! You could always change the positioning of the visible hexagons with JS. Looks good though!

Comment: Maybe [flex-box](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp) could help

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer alone by playing with jquery add/remove class. 
Not fancy and smart I guess, but that's a solution.

```
$(".filter-button").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');

    if(value == "all")
    {
        $('.filter').show('1000');

        $( "#sette" ).removeClass( "row1 col2 row1 col1 mb-2" )
        $( "#sette").addClass("row2 col2bis ");
        $( "#nove" ).removeClass( "row2 col1bis mb-6" )
        $( "#nove").addClass("row2 col4bis mb-9");
        $( "#otto" ).removeClass( "row1 col4" )
        $( "#otto").addClass("col3bis row2");
        $( "#sei" ).removeClass( "row1 col4" )
        $( "#sei").addClass("col1bis row2");
    }

    else
    {
        $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('3000');
        $('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('3000');


    if(value == "prodotti")
    {
        $( "#sette" ).removeClass( "row2 col2bis mb-7 row1 col1 " )
        $( "#sette").addClass("row1 col2 mb-2");
        $( "#nove" ).removeClass( "row2 col4bis mb-9" )
        $( "#nove").addClass("row2 col1bis mb-6");
    }

    if(value == "servizi")
    {
        $( "#sette" ).removeClass( "row1 col2 row2 col2bis mb-7 mb-2" )
        $( "#sette").addClass("row1 col1 mb-1");
        $( "#otto" ).removeClass( "col3bis row2 mb-8" )
        $( "#otto").addClass("row1 col4 mb-4");
    }

    if(value == "infestanti")
    {
        $( "#sette" ).removeClass( "row1 col2" )
        $( "#sette").addClass("row2 col2bis ");
        $( "#sei" ).removeClass( "col1bis row2 mb-6" )
        $( "#sei").addClass("row1 col4 mb-4");
    }
    }
});
```

});

Live preview: https://www.sebastianoriva.it/upload/esagoni/